# Use Knit2pdf to save only pdf output to another location

Tags: r, pdf, knitr

I am using Knit2pdf, but would like to save **only the .pdf file** to an external output file location, and not all the other files created in Knitr with it.

At the moment I am using the following:

```
opts_knit$set(base.dir = "outputfileloc")
Knit2pdf(input="inputfileloc/xxx.Rnw",output="outputfileloc")
```

This approach works, but I want "outputfileloc" to only store the pdf file and not all the other files (which I want to lie in the input folder inputfileloc.

Please assist.

Comment: use `file.copy` from the input input location to the output location

Comment: Thanks thats brilliant.